# Can I change the dalvik cache location e.g. with a symbolic link?

Tags: internal-storage, app2sd, dalvik, insufficient-memory

I currently use Link2SD since my phone's onboard storage is insufficient for more than a few essential apps. It is very effective but limited to when the phone is on.

While changing ROMs, the dalvik cache is wiped and when the phone restarts you see a progress bar saying Android is optimising applications. So given a reasonable number of applications, the dalvik cache fills up the storage long before link2sd can do anything about it.

So is there a way that mounts a sd card folder as the appropriate cache location before the system gets on with booting and doing its business? I know it might involve creating a symbolic link but I just don't know when things are mounted and in what order.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. Although it seems like there's no problem to migrate dalvik-cache to a normal SD card filesystem (the most common, vfat), it still is highly recommended that you format your SD card to ext4 (or the same as your `/data`) to ensure everything works fine.

So let's go. A full backup of all your apps is recommended before proceeding though if you feel lucky, it isn't required. Assuming that you have a terminal emulator to do the necessary jobs.

First, create a folder that you want to migrate your dalvik-cache to. Then `chmod` and `chown` the new folder to match `/data/dalvik-cache`. **If you're running a SELinux-enabled Android OS, don't forget to change security contexts correspondingly.** Run

```
ls -dlZ /data/dalvik-cache
ls -lZ /data/dalvik-cache
```

to see the original permissions, owner/groups and security contexts of dalvik-cache folder.

Next, copy all files from `/data/dalvik-cache` to your new location, for example `/storage/sdcard1/dalvik-cache`. You can use `cp -a` command to preserve file attributes, which would make things simpler.

**Ensure no new apps start during the process of the following step.**

Then, `rm -r /data/dalvik-cache` and create a symbolic link to the new location using

```
ln -s /storage/sdcard1/dalvik-cache /data/dalvik-cache
```

That's all. We're done. Reboot your phone (not required but recommended).

Some notices about this process:

1. The busybox may not always work well as Android is based on a highly modified Linux kernel. For example almost all SELinux-related functions do not work properly. You can test it out as shown below.

   ```
   toolbox ls -Z /data
   busybox ls -Z /data
   toolbox getenforce
   busybox getenforce
   ```

   However these may work properly, depending on Android version:

   ```
   busybox chcon <context> <files...>
   busybox runcon <context <program> [args...]
   ```
2. **Never** remove your SD card. If you re-format your SD card, make sure it's still ext4 AND create the dalvik-cache folder back **before** booting your phone for the first time.

Comment: I had no idea how wrote this comprehensive answer when I see it again after a year. Guess I've forgotten much about Android (which is of course, impossible).

Answer (score 1):

There are some nice Howtos available, which might prove helpful to solve your issue:

- [How to move dalvik cache to sd card (completely move all apps to sd card)](http://qwerandroidsite.blogspot.de/2012/06/how-to-move-dalvik-cache-to-sd-card.html)
- [Moving data and dalvik-cache to sd card to fix market issues](http://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-optimus-s-rooting-roms-hacks/106807-moving-data-dalvik-cache-sd-card-fix-market-issues.html)

According to several forum threads, [A2SDGUI - Darktremor A2SD GUI](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elgubbo.a2sdGUI) should be the app of choice to move the Dalvik cache to your SD card.

Comment: Would be nice if you could add some information from the links into your post

Comment: That's a bit too much stuff to integrate with my answer -- which is why I only extracted the basic hint, i.e. the app to do the work with.