# How can I move dalvik cache to a custom location(permanently)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, cache, dalvik, huawei-u8160

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change the dalvik cache location e.g. with a symbolic link?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20317/can-i-change-the-dalvik-cache-location-e-g-with-a-symbolic-link)

I have Huawei u8160 running Cyanogenmod 7.2.

I have activated `sd-ext` partition using Link2SD, so it's mounted on `/data/sdext2`, all the ways to move Dalvik cache to `sd-ext` requires ext partition to be mounted on `/sd-ext` .

Is there any way to move Dalvik cache to anywhere I want? Or at least to the specified location?

Comment: @Flow the ways mentioned in the answer don't work

Comment: @MohamedEssam Did you also check the linked information there?

Comment: @Izzy I think that http://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-optimus-s-rooting-roms-hacks/106807-moving-data-dalvik-cache-sd-card-fix-market-issues.html I should start off from 6 ,or what? but the problem is in 7 which I'll have to mount my sd-ext on `/sd-ext` to make this app work

Comment: @Izzy A2SDGUI script won't install ,CWM says "AMEND scripting (update-script) is no longer supported. AMEND scripting was deprecated by Google in Android 1.5. It was necessary to remove it when upgrading to the ClockworkMod 3.0 Gingerbread based recovery. Please switch to Edify scripting (updater-script and update-binary) to create working update zip packages. Installation aborted." , That means that I'll have to contact the developer to see why this error is happening with so I could be able to move the dalvik cache to my sd ext2 partition successfully ,that removes any link to that question.